# MYSQL - Retrieve related records from multiple rows in a single row

Tags: mysql, rows

I have this table:

```
person_id    first_name   middle_name    last_name    gender    form
P.1          John         null           null         null      form1
P.1          null         null           null         null      form1
P.1          null         R              null         null      form1
P.1          null         null           Doe          M         form1
P.2          Mary         null           null         null      form2
P.2          null         null           Jane         null      form2
```

How can I return the following result set:

```
person_id    first_name   middle_name    last_name    gender    form
P.1          John         R              Doe          M         form1
P.2          Mary         null           Jane         null      form2
```

Comment: Please review [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then show us how you are generating this table. As written, your question is impossible to answer.

Comment: and you current query is ... ?

Comment: @Alex - the query is the part I am not sure about.  A GROUP BY doesnt work.

Comment: show us what you did try so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/85ab4/1

```
SELECT person_id,
  MAX(first_name), 
  MAX(middle_name), 
  MAX(last_name), 
  MAX(gender),
  form
FROM my_table
GROUP BY person_id, form
```

but you should definitely change your db schema.